# Install single SSH key multiple times on single machine via puppet

Tags: ssh, puppet

I want to have one place where I have defined ssh keys for my users. These users can be in different (multiple) roles on single server. So I defined ssh_authorized_key as virtual and then wanted to realize them in different roles. Example:

```
@ssh_authorized_key {
    "user_a":
        tag     => ['deployer', 'developer', 'root'],
        key     => "xxx",
        type    => "ssh-dss",
        ensure  => present;
    "user_b":
        tag     => ['deployer', 'root'],
        key     => "yyy",
        type    => "ssh-dss",
        ensure  => present;
    "user_c":
        tag      => ['root', 'deployer'],
        key      => 'zzz',
        type => "ssh-rsa",
        ensure   => present;
}
```

And then realize them for *multiple* users on *single* node:

```
Ssh_authorized_key<| tag == 'root' |> {
    user    => 'root'
}

Ssh_authorized_key<| tag == 'deployer' |> {
    user    => 'deployer'
}
```

But puppet will install the certificates only for one user. I think that main concept of my solution is wrong. But I can't figure out how to install single certificate to multiple users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the main concept of your solution is wrong, but I think it is wrong far earlier than you suspect. The best practice is to *not* share accounts; each user should have an individual account and use `sudo` to perform tasks that require alternate privileges. If you honestly *must* share one or more accounts, then allow your users to `sudo su - ACCOUNT` instead of logging in directly as ACCOUNT. For example:

```
user { 'alice': groups => ['developer', 'deployer', 'root'] # other params... }
ssh_authorized_key { 'alice': #params }
```

Then add appropriate entries in your `/etc/sudoers` (also hopefully managed by puppet!):

```
# deployer group can run the deployment script without a password.
%deployer  ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/deploy
# developer group can run commands as 'developer'
%developer ALL = (developer) ALL
# or, if you actually *must* allow them to log in as 'developer'
%developer ALL = /usr/bin/su developer
```

Comment: Although this does not answer my question. I admit that this is correct solution and everybody should do it this way.